# DataGrid Scrolling / Sorting Error

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, collectionviewsource

I have a `Datagrid`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionViewSource.View}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding={Binding Id} IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding={Binding Name} />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

`MyCollectionViewSource` is defined as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<SimpleDataViewModel> ObservableData { get; set; }
public CollectionViewSource MyCollectionViewSource { get; set; }

public DataGridViewModel()
{
    ObservableData = new ObservableCollection<SimpleDataViewModel>(
                        AllData.Select(x => new SimpleDataViewModel(x)));

    MyCollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
    MyCollectionViewSource.Source = ObservableData;

    MyCollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(
        new SortDescription("Id", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    MyCollectionViewSource.View.Refresh();
}
```

When I scroll through my datagrid quickly, items become unsorted, and remain unsorted. This, obviously, is unwanted behavior. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

**Edit**
It looks like the error occurs only when scrolling quickly, not using the mousewheel. For anyone testing - Select the scrollbar and rapidly move it up and down.

Comment: Why are you binding `ItemsSource` to the `View` property of the `CollectionViewSource`?

Comment: @DanielMay I thought that was how it's supposed to be bound. When I just bind to the `CollectionViewSource` my datagrid isn't populated.

Comment: @Charles W - You need to add more details to the question because in sample code I tried this and it works perfectly fine. Also try to post small sample here replicating your issue.